# Visual Basic and tcp client implemented in C++ / Python

Tags: python, c++, vb.net

I would like to link my C++ library into visual basic gui. 
My c++ library is based on boost asio and google proto buffers. The library implements following interface

```
class ICommunicatorClient{
virtual void sendStopRequest()=0;
virtual void waitForStopResp()=0;
//...
```

Can you tell me the easiest way to deploy such code? I can rewrote the library code into Python but It is not possible to change implementation of the GUI.

Comment: Into *which* Visual Basic GUI? You chose the VBA tag, but a lot of people use that even though they mean classic VB6 or VB.NET. You want to be sure the right people see this and think in the right direction...

Comment: @CindyMeister I've just updated the tags. Thank you for your suggestion.